# Laravel Jobs on Queue misbehaving or code is

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, beanstalkd

I have a production APP that sends Messages in bulk to different API based on networks and countries. 
Every time Message is sent, it is pushed to Queue. We use Beanstalked and supervisor to monitor the queue.

This is my code for the job processing

```
$tosend = user_messages::with(['recipient' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('api_response', null)->where('status', null);
        }])->find($id);
        $recipients = $tosend->recipient;
        $user = User::find($tosend->user_id);
        $sender = $tosend->senderid;
        $themessage = $tosend->message;

        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
            //if user selects to send all sms through corporate route
            if ($tosend->do_corporate == 2) {
                $check = $this->PassRequiredPrecheckCorporate($recipient->recipient, $tosend->route_id, $user);
            } else {
                $check = $this->PassRequiredPrecheck($recipient->recipient, $tosend->route_id, $user);
            }
            $api = api::find($check['api']);
            if ($api->provider_id == 1) {
                $this->ProviderA($recipient, $sender, $themessage, $id, $check['cost'], $api, $tosend->message_type_id, $tosend->sms_pages, $user);
            } elseif ($api->provider_id == 2) {
                $this->ProviderB($recipient, $sender, $themessage, $id, $check['cost'], $api, $tosend->message_type_id, $tosend->sms_pages, $user, $tosend->do_corporate, $tosend->route_id);
            }
        }
        user_messages::where('id', $id)->update([
            'status' => 'Sent'
        ]);
```

I observed a problem that just cost me a lot in finance. I realised that messages are sent multiple times some even up to to 10 times when the number of recipients is much maybe in the region of 2000 plus recipients.
please note we update field "api_response" every time $recipient is sent message to.

This is my supervisor

```
 [program:app-worker]
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php /home/example/public_html/example.com/artisan queue:work beanstalkd --timeout=60--tries=5
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    user=loftysms
    numprocs=10
    redirect_stderr=true
    stdout_logfile=/home/example/public_html/example.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

I will appreciate every help we can get

Comment: `we update field "api_response"` - where, and how? The code you show does not show that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, `function providerA` and `function providerB` handles that. the problem I have here is that  `tosend` doesn't load latest data when job is retried